# React router rendering only the '/' path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I dont know what im doing wrong

```
  import React from 'react'
  import {render} from 'react-dom'
  import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

  class App extends React.Component {


     render(){
       return(
           <Router>
               <Route exact path="/" component={ Home } />
               <Route exact path="/test" component={ Foo } />

          </Router>
       )                                                      
    }                                                                                
 }                                                                                

 class Foo extends React.Component {                                              
    render(){                                                                    
        return(                                          
            <h1>Foo</h1>                                 
        )                                                  
    }                                                    
}                                                        
class Home extends React.Component {                     
    render(){                                            
       return(                                          
            <h1>This is the home path</h1>               
        )                                                
    }                                                
}                                                    

export default App
```

I can see the h1 of the Home component but cant see the Foo one.

I've seen other questions with the same issue but are all diferent.

Also if I change the '/' path to '/home' for example, like this

```
<Route exact path="/home" component={ Home } />
```

neither works, is like only working the '/' path, not the first path.

Comment: Can you explain what result you want? When the pathname is "/" you want the home component to render but when the pathname is "/test" you want both `Home` and `Foo` to render?

Comment: I want the Home component in the '/' path and Foo in '/test', for now I dont really care about rendering both in '/test'. The problem is the Foo component just cant render

Comment: Try the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x9hz8?file=/App.js) and let me know if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Yeah it works!, I copy and paste it and works, I realized that  works with the button but if I write the path (as I've been tried all the time) doesnt. thanks

Comment: Alright. I will post the solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Route` inside of `Switch` will render the first `Route` that matches the criteria. Also you can use the `Link` component to navigate between the paths. Here is an implementation of a  working solution.

Also, see the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x9hz8?file=/App.js:0-803) for demo

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/test" component={Foo} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h2>I am the foo component</h2>
        <Link to="/">
          <button>Go to Home</button>
        </Link>
      </>
    );
  }
}
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>This is the home path</h1>
        <Link to="/test">
          <button>Go to Test</button>
        </Link>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the exact attr from the /test route  and 
Enclosed with Switch component like this; without the Router

```
<Switch>

<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
 <Route path="/test" component={Foo} />
</Switch>


import { HashRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

 Try using the hashRouter from react-router-dom

             <HashRouter>                          
                   <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
 <Route path="/test" component={Foo} /> 
             </HashRouter>
```

Comment: hey mate, I tested out this code on code sandbox and it works fine

Comment: In my browser dont :( but if i go to the path with a button instead of writing the path in the browser works fine, its weird :/

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping Routes inside a Switch component?

Something like:

```html
<Router>
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={ Home } />
     <Route exact path="/test" component={ Foo } />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Do not forget to import Switch component from "react-router-dom"

**Update:**
Also remove the import line:

```js
  import {render} from 'react-dom'
```

Comment: remove the line   import {render} from 'react-dom' and try

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your webpack-config as :

```
output: {
   // ...
   publicPath: "/"
},
devServer: {
   historyApiFallback: true
}
```